# How to remove '\n' from values in dict? working with json file

Tags: python, dictionary

My json file looks like below:

```
[
    {
        "name": "\nsome information\n",
        "surname": "\nsome information\n",
        "date": "\nsome information\n",
        "email": "\nsome information\n"
    }
]
```

I need to remove \n from every value.

Do we have some way to remove it?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str.strip`

```
>>> data = [
    {
        "name": "\nsome information\n",
        "surname": "\nsome information\n",
        "date": "\nsome information\n",
        "email": "\nsome information\n"
    }
]

>>> [{key: value.strip() for key, value in d.items()} for d in data]
[
    {'name': 'some information',
     'surname': 'some information',
     'date': 'some information',
     'email': 'some information'}
]
```

If you have `'\n'` characters within the string that you want to replace, you could also use `str.replace('\n', '')`

```
[{key: value.replace('\n', '') for key, value in d.items()} for d in data]
```

Comment: Now I see that I have as well \n inside of value like "something \ninteresting" :(

Comment: @name_of_user See the most recent edit to my answer, you can handle those cases too

Answer (score 0):

```
for key in listy[0]:
    listy[0][key] = listy[0][key].strip("\n")
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
json_ = [
    {
        "name": "\nsome information\n",
        "surname": "\nsome information\n",
        "date": "\nsome information\n",
        "email": "\nsome information\n"
    }
]


for item in json_:
    for key, value in item.items():
        item[key] = value.strip()

print(json_)
```

Answer (score 0):

In just ONE line (without loop)

Data:

```
d = [
    {
        "name": "\nsome information\n",
        "surname": "\nsome information\n",
        "date": "\nsome information\n",
        "email": "\nsome information\n"
    }
]
```

d:

```
[{'name': '\nsome information\n',
  'surname': '\nsome information\n',
  'date': '\nsome information\n',
  'email': '\nsome information\n'}]
```

```
[dict(zip(d[0].keys(), list(map(str.strip, d[0].values()))))]
```

```
[{'name': 'some information',
  'surname': 'some information',
  'date': 'some information',
  'email': 'some information'}]
```